# Entity Framework 6 connection string questions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC code first project that works as intended to connect to my database.  It has the connection string set in the web.config file and all seems to work great.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HorstMFGContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|HorstMFG.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HorstMFG;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Now I need to connect to the same database from a different application that needs to be a WinForms based class library.  I don't have access to the source code of the program that uses my dll because my application is just a plug-in for Autodesk Vault.

There are numerous examples [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405873/how-do-i-configure-entity-framework-in-class-library-project?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) that show how to set the connection string in the application that calls the dll, but that obviously won't work in my case.

[This link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440405/entity-framework-6-set-connection-string-runtime) seems to very close to what I need, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Here is my version of the 'Create' function.

```
public static HorstMFGEntities Create(string nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            // use your ADO.NET connection string
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString;

            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/HorstMFG.ssdl|res://*/HorstMFG.msl";


            return new HorstMFGEntities(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);
        }
```

Here is the line that calls the function:

```
using (var db  = HorstMFGEntities.Create(@"data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=C:\Users\lorne\source\repos\HorstMFG\HorstMFG\App_Data\HorstMFG.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"))
                {
                    foreach (string l in lineList3)
                    {
                       ....
                       ....
```

Here is the actual line that throws the exception.

```
// calculate material
                        Material mat = db.Materials.Where(m => m.StructuralCode == l.Split('\t')[6]).FirstOrDefault();
```

The exception message "Error: Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.

Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks.

I updated my code as per the first comment, and also added the 'provider' that I had missed as well.

```
public static HorstMFGEntities Create(string nameOrConnectionString)
        {
            var entityBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            // use your ADO.NET connection string
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString;

            entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/HorstMFG.csdl|res://*/HorstMFG.ssdl|res://*/HorstMFG.msl";


            return new HorstMFGEntities(entityBuilder.ConnectionString);
        }
```

Now I get the error "Error: Unable to load the specified resource."

I now followed the instructions in the [link you provided.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092218/dynamic-connection-string-for-ef-code-first) I think I must be getting close, but I'm a little foggy on the metadata format yet.  There seems to be a portion commented out in the example.  I replaced it with this:

```
entityBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/HorstMFG.csdl|res://*/HorstMFG.ssdl|res://*/HorstMFG.msl";
```

Now I get the error: "Unable to load the specified metadata resource"

I confirmed that the files I am referencing do exist, they are in the ...\obj\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed\ folder in my project.  I also changed the 'build action' for the 'HorstMFG.edmx' object from 'None' to 'Embedded Resource'.  That didn't help anything.

[image]

Comment: I used this connection builder class a few years ago and I know it works...did notice a difference in your example and the one you linked to.   Your version is missing the "Model.csdl" in the meta...pretty sure EF requires all 3 res links.   Try it like this and see if it works.    res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl

Comment: EF code first needs none of them.

Comment: See additional info in edited question.

Comment: Sorry, I glossed over the fact you were doing code first...take a look at this SO question...it's more inline with what you are trying to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092218/dynamic-connection-string-for-ef-code-first

Comment: Added more details to original question.